# update or insert in sqlite3

Tags: linux, sqlite

Am using sqlite3 in linux machines.

I need to update the values if primary key exists, else record should be inserted. Is there any query statement for this.

Answer (score 3):

[REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) you should use

```
insert or replace into t (a, b, c) values ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

this is an example....